# CSS fade in fade out gives a weird blink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a website and wanted to add a simply fade in/fade out for my content. But whenever I try to go change between pages, I get this weird white "blink", although sometimes it works just perfectly, but for the most part I get the blink.
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#content").css("display", "none");
        $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
        $("a").click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            linkLocation = this.href;
            $("#content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
        });
        function redirectPage() {
            window.location = linkLocation;
        }
    });
</script>
```

My HTML is, i've removed some things from the original code since I could have that much code, but here is the crucial part:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Projekt 4</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">        
            <div id="content">

                <h2 id="rubrik">Välkommen</h2>
                <p id="text">Du befinner dig nu på min förstasida i min hemsida. För 
                     att ta dig vidare och hitta så välj bland valen i navigeringen. 
                     <br> Har du några frågor eller kommentarer kan du nå mig genom fältet 
                     här till höger.</p>

                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#content").css("display", "none");
                        $("#content").fadeIn(1000);
                        $("a").click(function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            linkLocation = this.href;
                            $("#content").fadeOut(1000, redirectPage);
                        });
                        function redirectPage() {
                            window.location = linkLocation;
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </div>  
        </div>   

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: add your html also

Comment: My guess would be that you're adding `display: none` with jQuery when the Dom is loaded. I would just add this as a css property rather than adding the style with JS.

Comment: he is on the first line `$("#content").css("display", "none");` , @BrandonMowat

Comment: He's adding it with JavaScript, which is only being executed when the DOM is ready. Using CSS would perform much better. Prior to that being executed, the element will likely have `display: block`.

Comment: yeah ! thats what I was saying go ahead add an answer :) @BrandonMowat

Comment: Sorry for my understanding, but what does it mean to use it in css? Am I supposed to insert it as part of the code in the css file?

Answer (score 0):

I think the flash is happening due to the fact that you're adding the CSS property `display: none` with jQuery, which is only executed after the DOM is ready. Prior to this, the element has `display: block`.

I think a simple inline CSS property of `display: none` would do the trick.